# Маска ввода для поля даты

Tags: javascript, jquery

Хотел написать маску ввода для для поля `<input type="text" id="test" />`, но что-то не соображу как это сделать. 
Формат ввода следующий -  пользователь может ввести число в диапазоне `01-31` (если число меньше `10`, то должно быть `01,02,03`...). Дальше вводим `точку`. Дальше месяц - `01-12`, снова `точка`. Дальше год - `4 цифры`. Заранее спасибо всем откликнувшимся!

Comment: что такое "маска"? регулярное выражение?

Comment: маска - т.е. в реальном времени пользователь может вводить данные согласно условию из описания. Может ввести только число 0, затем число 1-9, или же 10-31. Затем точку. Это ввели день. Так же для месяца (с учётом того, что их 12). И год - 4 цифры

Comment: ок, обновил ответ.

Comment: А почему вы не хотите просто взять `<input type='date' id='test'>`?

Comment: @Darth только это не везде будет работать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно повесить на события изменения содержимого поля обработчик, проверяющий соответствие ввода регулярному выражению. Если соответствует - делать ничего, если не соответствует - откатывать к предыдущему значению и показывать пользователю предупреждение, мол, так нельзя.

Вот возможный [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15504877/1688077): вот регулярное выражение, принимающее даты в форматах `дд/мм/гггг`, `дд-мм-гггг` и `дд.мм.гггг`:

```
^(?:(?:31(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[13578]|1[02]))\1|(?:(?:29|30)(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[1,3-9]|1[0-2])\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$|^(?:29(\/|-|\.)0?2\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$|^(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])(\/|-|\.)(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$
```

Если хотите разрешить только `дд.мм.гггг`, то делайте так:

```
^(?:(?:31(\.)(?:0?[13578]|1[02]))\1|(?:(?:29|30)(\.)(?:0?[1,3-9]|1[0-2])\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$|^(?:29(\.)0?2\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$|^(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])(\.)(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$
```

[image: визуализация]

[Визуализация: Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/8x1Fz1T_riSd7nhg)

Впрочем, для современных браузеров можно не городить обработчики, а использовать [встроенную проверку](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21906272/1688077).

А ещё можно использовать [плагин к jQuery](http://www.thimbleopensource.com/tutorials-snippets/jquery-plugin-filter-text-input), раз уж автор им пользуется.

Comment: Проблема в том, что не знаю, как завернуть выражение в скрипт. пробовал так: $("#test").keydown(function (event) {
            var value = this.value;
            var reg = /Здесь выражение/;
            
            if (!reg.test(value)) {
                this.value = value.slice(0, -1);
            }
        
    });

Comment: AntonioK, сделал как Вы предложили. При выполнении события change делается проверка на соответствие введённого в поле значения регулярному выражению. Если не соответствует, то поле просто очищается.